# Is it possible to map a servlet to /* without overriding JSP processing

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Elaborating on this:

I map a servlet or filter to "/*"

Now, if I access a url like:

```
/test
```

Then this will be directed to the servlet (which is okay)

But if i access a url like:

```
/index.jsp
```

This will be directed also to the servlet, I dont want this behavior, what I want is for index.jsp to be processed as jsp.

How can this be done?

Comment: Yes, But the best way to do that depends on what server and frameworks you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map your controller servlet on a more specific `url-pattern` like `/controller/*` and create a `Filter` which is mapped on `/*` and does roughly like follows in `doFilter()` method.

```
String uri = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
if (uri.endsWith(".jsp")) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response); // Just let it go. The container's builtin JspServlet will pickup this.
} else {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/controller" + uri).forward(request, response); // Goes to controller servlet.
}
```

Comment: The closest answer. But wouldn't the forward call break the filter chain? How can this be handled.

Comment: The forward will call filters with `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>` as well.

Comment: I've just tried it, it still has many problems. The *.css files get treated non jsp and thus errors take place. I dont think I'll use it, but its nice to know.

Comment: Let their uri start with for example `/static` or `/resources` and then add an extra check in the `if`.